# f be a function such that f"(x)>0 for all x $\epsilon \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This question was asked in a masters exam for which I am preparing and I was unable to solve it. So, I am asking for help here.

> Let f be a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Given that f''(x)>0 for all x $\epsilon \mathbb{R}$. Then which 1 of the following is true:

(i) f(x) =0 has exactly 2 solutions.

(ii)f(x)=0 has a positive solution if f(0)=0and f'(0)=0.

(iii) f(x)=0 has no positive solution if f(0)=0 and f'(0)>0.

(iv) f(x)=0 has no positive solution if f(0)=0 and f'(0)<0.

(i) can be contradicted by taking f(x)=$e^x$ and (ii) using f(x)= $e^x -x-1$. But I don't know how to contradict other options. I tried using log x but that will not work . So, kindly tell me how to approach the other 2 options.

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you think of examples of functions satisfying the condition? Have you eliminated any of the possiblities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iii) is true: If $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ then, for any $y \in (0,x)$ we have $y=(1-t)(0)+tx$ where $t =\frac y x$. Since $f$ is convex we get $f(y) \leq (1-t)f(0)+tf(x)=0$. But $f'(0)>0$ forces $f(y)$ to be $>0$ for $y$ sufficiently close to $0$.

EDIT: A simpler argument for iii): Since $f'$ is increasing we get $f'(x) \geq f'(0)$ for all $x>0$. Let $x>0$. MVT gives $f(x)=f(x)-f(0)=(x-0)f'(t) \geq xf'(0)>0$ for all $x >0$, where $t$ is some number between $0$ and $x$. Hence $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

You may also note that $f(x)=(x-\frac  1 2)^{2}-\frac1  4$ gives a counter-example for iv).